# GetValues SetValues Basic Syntax Question

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want eliminate formula information that is in an array of cells. My idea was to get the values of the cells as an array and then set the values back into the same place. I can't get it to work and have a feeling it due to my syntax. Any suggestions?

```
function getset() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var places = ss.getRange(2,11, lr-1).getValues();
  ss.getRange(2,11, lr-1).setValues(places);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
function getset() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var places = sh.getRange(2,11, lr-1).getValues();
  sh.getRange(2,11, lr-1).setValues(places);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. What is the logic behind when to call the sheet vs. when to call the spreadsheet?

Comment: Look at the documentation for Class Spreadsheet and Class Sheet.  You will see that they have different methods